# Feign client: final fields of payload object are not serialized when executing POST form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

In my code I have simple Feign client:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "client", url = "${spring.microservice.tenant-auth.host}")
public interface PerTenantTokenClient {

  @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
  ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> getAuthToken(AuthFormData formData);

}
```

aimed to execute the following request:

```
POST https://myhost.net/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type = client_credentials &
client_id = id &
client_secret = secret
```

`getAuthToken()` method accepts a payload DTO described as:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthFormData {
  private final String grant_type;
  private final String client_id;
  private final String client_secret;
}
```

When I run this code snippet:

```java
AuthFormData authFormData = new AuthFormData("client_credentials", "id", "secret");
var authTokenResponse = client.getAuthToken(authFormData);
```

it unexpectedly fails with 400:

```
[400 Bad Request] during [POST] to [https://myhost.net/oauth/token] [PerTenantTokenClient#getAuthToken(AuthFormData)]: [{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Missing parameter: grant_type"
}]
```

However, if I remove `final` from `AuthFormData` fields' declaration the same code succeeds.

I've tried to declare `AuthFormData` as Java record and it fails either (apparently due to implicit `final` on record members).

So my question is whether I'm facing a bug in feign client or something is wrong with my code? I use `io.github.openfeign:feign-core:13.1` and Java 21

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, see the following links:

- https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/2152
- https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form/pull/120